# How do we show Totals and Subtotals in SAPUI5 analytical table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

In smart table I want to show both totals and subtotals for hours column. I have created smart table with `tableType = "AnalyticalTable"` and in the backend we have created `sap:semantics="aggregate"` for EntitySet and `sap:aggregation-role="measure"` for hours column and `sap:aggregation-role="dimension"` for other properties for grouping. I tried using `summed = true` for Analytical column but not able to show totals. Also, I have tried Total/TotalBy annotations. But they also didn't work.

```
<Annotations Target="Metadata.Cats_Da/">
     <Annotation Term="UI.PresentationVariant">
            <Record Type="UI.PresentationVariantType">
                <PropertyValue Property="Total">
                  <Collection>
                    <PropertyPath>Hours</PropertyPath>
                  </Collection>
                </PropertyValue>    
           </Record>
            </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

In Header item menu 'Total' is showing but not able to aggregate. It's displaying as below. We would like to perform totals and subtotals.

[image]

Could you please provide suggestions? I am not sure what we are missing.

Comment: Any suggestion on above issue please.